# Can I retrieve POP3 mail with PHP from different server?

Tags: php, email, pop3

I tried to retrieve my POP3 E-Mail with PHP from a different server which is out of E-Mail server's domain, by referring to simple sample PHP codes for test.

But I have encountered some errors such as 'imap_open : couldn't open stream...', searched for answers,
I found an answer that I need to check the user name and password, a server might block the E-Mail transfer, etc.

Because I have no experience on mail processing with PHP,
I have doubt if I can access the E-Mail server from another server, where my PHP code is in.

Because my E-Mail server is a commercial one, I cannot upload my PHP file on the server.

Can I create a web E-Mail client to retrieve my mails from the E-Mail server?

I will be appreciated for any help of you,
Thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue. It would be no different from conencting via an email client. However, I remember finding the IMAP function a bit difficult to get working, as the docs are not great and there can be a lot of variety in email settings. Sorry I cannot offer specific advice.

Comment: check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php#100827) it might help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer would simply be "yes this is possible".